# Read unknown data from yml configuration file

Tags: java, yaml, config, bukkit

I'm writing a bukkit plugin which should read data from a yml configuration file made by users like shown in the example below.
I've searched for that before with no result, in fact I don't really know what I should search for.

Example config:

```
maps:
  01:
    name: world
    displayname: Plains
    icon: 2
    size: 1000
    info:
    - 'Some information'
    - 'Another information string'
  02:
    name: world_nether
    displayname: Nether
    icon: 87
    size: 500
    info:
    - 'Information'
    - 'More information'
    - 'As many lines as needed...'
```

The number of maps is unknown, the user can create as many as he wants, so there are not only `01` and `02`, the content (`name`, `icon`, `info`,...) is always the same.

How can I read out the number of `maps` (`01`, `02`,...) and what is a good way to save the different types of content (strings, integers, lists) in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `Set<String>` of the children.

See [ConfigurationSection](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/Configuration.java), [FileConfiguration](https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/configuration/file/FileConfiguration.java)

```
FileConfiguration fc = getConfig(); // Get the config
ConfigurationSection cs = fc.getConfigurationSection("maps");
boolean deep = false; 
for (String key : cs.getKeys(deep)) {
    //Key will be 01
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an Argument `/[yourcommand] [Number] [...]`.
If you don´t want a command you can save a Line like: `Worlds: 1` When you create a new `arena` you can get the Number from `Worlds` and override it.